# which CSS properties go into Id and which ones into class

Tags: css

I'm writing my first [web site](http://libreriamusicale.altervista.org/), it's a small one with four pages. Every page has the four common structural elements: header, nav, div id="content" and footer.

Next, I am adding CSS properties to the HTML elements and I have used both ID and classes to hook them in CCS style sheet.
I have [read](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) that it is right to use both id and class for an element, so I am wondering which CSS properties I have to write into CSS id rules and which ones into CSS class rules.

I want to make an example. I should write the following CSS rule:

```
.centered_box{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

and then apply it to the structural elements: header, main and footer or it is best to repeat margin and width properties into the id CSS rules of the structural elements:

```
header, nav, footer, div#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: `#id` and `.class`.. unfortunately this is probably going to be closed..

Comment: there aren't properties that belong in one that do not belong in the other, just put the properties in the selector that is easier to use

Comment: If you are writing HTML5 there is most likely no use for identifying the elements using classes / ids. Just use the HTML elements [`<header>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html), [`<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/nav.html), [`<footer>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/footer.html).

Comment: Since ids are unique you typically apply styles that are unique to an element using the id selector, and since classes are meant to be shared across multiple elements you apply all common styles there

Comment: Please read about [css specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). You add css rules based on what you want styled. A selector with an id will always trump a selector with just classes, just like a selector with just classes will beat a selector with just elements.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use all properties with id and same properties with class also.
- The basic difference between id and class is,

  - id is used to uniquely identify the element, and you can use style for it. Every element will have different id(logically).
  - You can use class for many elements where you want to apply same style properties.
- See the simple example below.

  #but{background-color:red;}

  .but1{background-color:blue;}
- Here #but is id, means only single button having this id will have red background. 
  and .but1 is class means all the buttons having this class will have blue background color.

Comment: I have just edited my question now, may I ask you to read it again. What do you think about the sample code?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't specific properties, the only difference between a class and an ID is the fact that the ID is to be used once on the web page and the class is to be used multiple times

Comment: I have just edited my question now, can you read it again. What do you think about the sample code?

Comment: @user1820567 It doesn't matter... you'd just use .class for a generic style like if you wanted to turn two separate paragraphs to a specific colour you could do .example { color:#CCCCCC; } and then on both paragraphs you could add the class. But for the ID, it identifies the element so it can only be used once on the webpage, that's all you really need to know about it